# Log in with email after signing up with Google

Tags: support

I have signed up on Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites with my Google account.

When I try to log in with my email address, I get an error saying that my email is incorrect. So, I have to keep using my Google account. What can I do?

Comment: Go to your profile, Under Edit Profile & Settings, select My logins & add a new login with your email id

Comment: @KharoBangdo No password was set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that if you sign up with *Google*, no password is set.

So, what I had to do was to *add* a password. For anybody who experiences this issue, here are the steps:

---

1. ***Log out*** of you account.
2. *After that, you'll be directed to the **homepage***.
3. *Tap the **sign in** button*.
4. *Type your **email*** (*optional*).
5. *By your password, you'll see a link saying **`Forgot?`**, tap it*.
6. *You'll be directed to a page called **Account Recovery**, where you'll have to **type your email***.
7. *Open your email and look for a link saying **`set a password here`**, then tap that link*.
8. *Type in your new password **twice***.

   - *The **first** input is for the password*.
   - *The **second** input is for confirmation*.

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you're signed in, you can also just go to My Logins in the Edit Profile screen and add a new login. Enter the email and password there. The account recovery system can sometimes cause it to not get attached to your account and instead create a new one in some weird edge cases. Users should avoid doing it that way unless they're actually locked out of their account